# How do I properly insert my own trywithresources code template in netbeans.

Tags: java, netbeans

I realized that the ff code block below has like hundreds of them in a big project I'm working on. So I thought that maybe if there's a way for me to *automatically insert* the ff code on **CTRL+SPACE** would speed up my development instead of retyping the block everytime which *consumes several seconds to minutes.* If I multiply those seconds / minutes to the sum of methods I need to write, I know it will be equivalent to hours of wasted time.

I'm able generate some common code templates by **CTRL+SPACE**. For instance `trycatch` then CTRL+SPACE. I researched online and found out that I can create my own code template by going to **Tools > Options > Editor > Code Templates > New > OK**. So I did. But when I returned to my project to test it out, I get nothing when I type the name of the code template I created.

```
try (Connection con = DBUtil.getConnection(DBType.MYSQL);) {
    con.prepareCall(SQLa);
    try (CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall(SQLa);) {
        //My implementation goes here.
        con.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        con.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I named it "**jdbctrans**" without quotes. Nothing on CTRL+SPACE

I would appreciate if you can help me do it correctly in NETBEANS as it will save me time. I have like hundreds of methods more to write for this big project. I don't want to keep typing it everytime I write a method.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered "ctrl-c" and "ctrl-v", or even better - extracting this pattern to a method, or looking to see if someone else already has? Apache [for example](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/DbUtils.html).

Answer (score 0):

Code templates in netbeans are triggered typing the abbreviation in sequence(aka. no backspace , delete or arrow in the middle) and then pressing TAB.

In your case if everything was configured correctly you should type jdbctrans and then TAB.

You can try some of the built-ins templates to make sure, like "2al" TAB or "psfi" TAB.

Edit:
You can also manually change the trigger key to ENTER, SHIFT+SPACE, SPACE. If you changed the default config you might wanna try those keys as well.